# Auth using LDAP - where is a good place to put the LDAP connection check?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

My app uses Windows Authentication to get the user's credentials and check them against the Active Directory via LDAP

It doesn't use Laravel's Auth, or any session, it simply verifies the user on every request (It's an internal system so the connection to the LDAP is pretty quick)

The verification is a simple LDAP connection that checks if the user's credentials really exists in the AD. The credentials themselves are automatically passed in the request via the `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` variable

Currently I place the trait on every Controller, but maybe I can do it better, and put it someone else? Maybe `AppServiceProvider` or `AuthServiceProvider`'s `boot()`? Where would be a proper place for this LDAP verification?

Comment: If it's something that has to happen in every request, why not create a Middleware for it?

Comment: I don't know why I was looking in so complex places, when Middleware really seem to be the right choice. I will definitely use a Middleware. I have another question, but maybe that requires a different post: I need the LDAP credentials in the Controllers as well, so if I verify the user in a Middleware, how can I pass the credentials to be available in the Controller? Because I later need to use these credentials for DB operations

Comment: You say they are in the `$_SERVER` global, right? You can access that with `request()->server(key, default)` as well. Or `$request->server(key, default).` For example `$request->server('AUTH_USER');`

Comment: Yes, might try. It's just that, the global only holds the username, but I then get the full user details from the database, so I wanted to get the actual `User` ready, I will just make a trait maybe so that I can do something like `$user = $this->getLdapUser();`. Thank you!

Comment: You can do something like that in the middleware as well. I'll post a more detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Middleware, you can use the `Request`'s `setUserReolver()` method in it.

```
class yourMiddleware extends Middleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->setUserResolver(function ($guard = null) use ($request) {
            // I'm not familiar with ldap but here
            // you need to write the logic necessary
            // to return the user. You have the $request available.

            return $user;
        });

        $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now, in your controller

```php
class yourController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) // <- request that has gone through the middleware
    {
        // You are able to access the user with
        $request->user();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to override `$request->user()`'s default behavior with this, you can pass in a `guard`.

```php
$request->setUserResolver(function ($guard = null) use ($request) {
    if ($guard === 'ldap') {
        // I'm not familiar with ldap but here
        // you need to write the logic necessary
        // to return the user. You have the $request available.

        return $user;
    }
});
```

```php
$request->user()       // default behavior, web guard
$request->user('ldap') // gets into the callback's if statement.
```